# When running rails server I get the following error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macports

```
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::Error)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When running psql -h localhost I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My System Setup:
Mac OSX 10.7.5 and everything was installe with Macports.

Comment: looks like you just need to start postgres

Comment: if you run `ps aux | grep postgres` in your terminal, what do you get?